# Move element after nth paragraph with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to move move a div `#inject` from its original postion to right after the 7th paragraph `#mw-content-text`.

So far I have this `$('#inject').insertAfter('#mw-content-text > p:nth-child(7)');` which is moving the `#inject` div to right after the 7th elment inside `#mw-content-text` only if that 7th elment is a `<p>`, if its something different it wont do anything.

For example if the article has the following structure it works (since the 7th elment is a `<p>`)

```
<div id="mw-content-text">
    <table></table>
    <h2></h2>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <h2></h2>
    <p></p>
    /* div #inject is injected here */
    <p></p>
    <h2></h2>
    ...
```

If the article looks like this on the other hand (were the 7th elment is an `<h2>`) then it does nothing

```
<div id="mw-content-text">
    <table></table>
    <h2></h2>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <h2></h2>
    <p></p>
    <h2></h2>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <h2></h2>
    <p></p>
    ...
```

Can anybody see what I'm doing wrong? What would be the proper way to refer to the 7th `<p>` element inside #mv-content-text instead of the 7th element only when its a `<p>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `p:nth-of-type(7)` instead of `p:nth-child(7)`.

**Details:**

- `p:nth-child(7)` means *give me the element if it is a `<p>` element and if it is the 7<sup>th</sup> child of its parent*
- `p:nth-of-type(7)` means *give me the 7<sup>th</sup> `<p>` element*

Comment: Indeed! Thank you so much! :)

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the [eq](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) function. Like this:

```
$('#inject').insertAfter($('#mw-content-text>p').eq(6));
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qkjws7jv/

Just note that `eq` is zero-based hence the 6 instead of 7